# Тратятся ли ресурсы на элементы layout, которые не видны (не влезают) на экран?

Tags: java, android-layout

Я так думаю, что тратятся: и кнопки создаются, неважно gone они или visible, или вообще находятся вне области экрана, и картинки загружаются?
Правильно ли я понимаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В целом да, но есть нюансы. YouTube видео, например, не загружается, если находится в div с display: none;

Comment: спасибо, а есть алгоритм проверки входит или не входит элемент в области видимости?

Comment: Есть, конечно. Задайте вопрос, и я опубликую ответ на jQuery